# rake db:seed won't seed all the data in production

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, seed

I have a seeds.rb file with data to seed. Not all the data gets seeded and `rake db:seed` ends with a message `killed` in the terminal. The same, however, works for development environment.
Here's the part I want to be seeded

```
xls_utility = Roo::Spreadsheet.open('/path/to/data.xlsx')
utilities = []
xls_utility.each do |row|
  utility = Utility.new
  if row[0] != "State"
  ["state_code", "value"].each_with_index do |attribute, index|
    utility[attribute] = row.flatten[index]
  end
    utilities << utility
  end
end
Utility.import utilities
```

Comment: I tried using `rails.application.load_seed`.. no luck

Comment: Are you metioning the RAILS_ENV in the rake task ? Just tru this : `rake RAILS_ENV=production db:seed`

Comment: yes, I am mentioning RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: I was doing `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed` is that not correct?

Comment: Can you paste some more elaborative error message which occurs on running the seed task ?

Comment: Here's the message 
`Table roles truncated.
Table states truncated.
Table cities truncated.
Table pv_modules truncated.
Table invertors truncated.
Table mounts truncated.
Table pitches truncated.
Table azimuths truncated.
Table utilities truncated.
Killed`

Comment: @geeku not sure if you know what `truncate` means but it means - Removes all rows from a table without logging the individual row deletions. So from the looks of that log it is removing all the rows in your tables.

Comment: I think it removes and then adds. Like i said, Works perfectly for dev environment

Comment: Can you paste the code for `import` method ? and `truncate` by the way only removes all the data, it doesn't adds again.

Comment: cheek have you run all the migrations on production database?, try running rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production, and then do rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production.

Comment: I have done that twice in the same order

Comment: The code above doesn't have the truncate code, it only shows how a table will be populated.

Comment: try check your Gemfile, that is there any gem that is needed in production environment but you have put it in development group only, read production log

Comment: I have the same gem files in production as I have in development. after which I ran bundle install.

Comment: In last case, try to generate a coredump and see what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed to seed data to some tables and since `rake db:seed` didn't seem to work.
Exporting and importing table in mysql was an alternative.
Export from local

```
mysqldump -p - -user=username dbname utilites > utilities.sql
```

Import from production

```
mysql -u username -p -D dbname < utilities.sql
```

However, I still want to know why rails seeding won't work. Thanks